# how to change the number of total rows in datatable

Tags: datatable

I'm developing an application with Symfony 3 in which I'm using datatables.

to avoid getting all rows of database, I'm using doctrine's paginator. so i want the datatable will get 100 elements first, then when I click in next button it will charge the next 100 elements.

My problem is that when setting datatable with first 100 elements, I can't click on next button. ( because it's showing the 100 elements so there are no other elements for it). I want to tell it that I have more than 100 elements. so how can I do it.

My table :

```html
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered  dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
                   id="table_city">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Region</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th class="no-sort">Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for core_city in core_cities %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ core_city.code }}</td>
                        <td>{{ core_city }}</td>
                        <td>{{ core_city.CoreRegion }}</td>
                        <td>{{ core_city.CoreRegion.coreCountry }}</td>
                        <td class="datatable_td_buttons">
                            <a class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn  m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill"
                               title="Show" href="{{ path('core_city_show', { 'id': core_city.id }) }}">
                                <i class="la la-search"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="{{ path('core_city_edit', { 'id': core_city.id }) }}"
                               class="m-portlet__nav-link btn  m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Edit">
                                <i class="la la-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="{{ path('core_zip_code_import_by_city', { 'id': core_city.id } ) }}"
                               class="m-portlet__nav-link btn  m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill"
                               title="Import Zip Code">
                                <i class="la la-upload"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: You must use serverside processing, it seems that there is a symfony bundle for this here -> **https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "infoCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {
    return start +" to "+ end;
  }
} );
```